# RODBC changing limit for group_concat

Tags: mysql, r, limit, group-concat, rodbc

I am using RODBC to connect R to a MySQL database. I have to use a group_concat in the select of my SQL query and I would like to change the default size limitation of the group_concat function.

```
test = sqlQuery(connect, "SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000; select group_concat(name) from country")
```

But I get the following error message:

```
[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000; select group_concat(name) from country'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to put two SQL queries into one call to RODBC's `sqlQuery()` method. You Can't Do That (tm).  Call `sqlQuery()` for the `SET` query and again for the `SELECT` query.